# CSV - How to match similar data and merge files with batch?

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have two CSV files that I need to merge to be able to be read properly. An issue that I'm running into is matching coordinating data together before/after merging.

I need to be able to match the data up so that the chart is sorted. It's hard to explain, but I've included an example to help explain what I'm going for.

In the CSV files I have a few columns that I'm trying to merge, for example the first CSV file looks something like the following.

```
"ID","Ver","P/N"
"2000-00","3","abc"
"2001-00","1","acd"
"2001-01","5","acd"
"3111-00","2","xyz"
```

My second CSV file looks something like this:

```
"Number","Name"
"1000-00_efg_Ver-1","efg"
"2000-00_abc_Ver-3","abc"
"2001-00_acd_Ver-1","acd"
"3111-00_xyz_Ver-2","xyz"
"4290-01_lmn_Ver-2","lmn"
```

I would like to be able to run a script to merge the CSV files into a single CSV file similar to this:

```
ID,Ver,P/N,Number,Name
2000-00,3,abc,2000-00_abc_Ver-3 /abc,abc
2001-00,1,acd,2001-00_acd_Ver-1 /acd,acd
3111-00,2,xyz,3111-00_xyz_Ver-2 /xyz,xyz
```

So the script (doesn't have to be batch but is preferred) would only merge the columns that matched, and would drop all of the other data.

Any assistance on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

### -

EDIT:

After looking around the web a bit more, would it make sense to import my data into a database, run a query and then export the query as a CSV file?

This should work, but if I do it this way, I need to be able to run the commands remotely at certain times per day.

### -

Comment: Take a look at PowerShell, where you could use Data table objects to manipulate the data and the create a new CSV and/or Excel files.

Comment: Do read [Ask], and [MCVE]. If you [search SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Merge+CSV+files) you will find many answers to this problem, including [a bunch of batch-file solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5DMerge+CSV+files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I'd liked to see some coding effort from you as `SO` isn't a code writing service.
With files named first.csv, second.csv and third.csv

This batch should do:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\04\26\SO50049573.cmd
@Echo off
( Echo:ID,Ver,P/N,Number,Name
  for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in (first.csv) do (
      findstr "^\"%%~A_%%~C_Ver-%%~B\""  second.csv >nul 2>&1 && (
          Echo:%%~A,%%~B,%%~C,%%~A_%%~C_Ver-%%~B /%%~C,%%~C
      )
  )
) >third.csv
```

Sample output

```
> type third.csv
ID,Ver,P/N,Number,Name
2000-00,3,abc,2000-00_abc_Ver-3 /abc,abc
2001-00,1,acd,2001-00_acd_Ver-1 /acd,acd
3111-00,2,xyz,3111-00_xyz_Ver-2 /xyz,xyz
```

---

- As the content presented is completely redundant, there is no need to read cols from second.csv
- the findstr just checks if the constructed Name is present
- and if found builds the output string as requested.